# How to get similar text from database?

Tags: php, database

i have code like this =

```
<?php
  $sql=mysql_query("select first_name, middle_name, last_name, address, mothers_name from tabel");
  while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
      $firstname=$s['first_name'];
      $middlename=$s['middle_name'];
      $lastname=$s['last_name'];    
      $name_all= "$firstname"."&nbsp;$middlename"."&nbsp;$lastname";
      similar_text($name_all, $name_all, $percent); 
      echo "Presentasi = $percent %";
  } 
?>
```

but the result every name is 100%

```
example:
1 Adi Surya 100%
2 Budi Surya 100%
3 Surya Adi 100%
```

I want the result like this =

```
1 Adi Surya 63%
1 Surya Adi 63%
2 Budi Surya
```

Please help me what should i do ?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the code above? In `similar_text($name_all, $name_all, $percent);` you are passing name_all twice? Is the expected?

Comment: You're comparing $name_all to $name_all, what do you expect???

Comment: i mean how to get similar text on database ?

Comment: You should give [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) a try.  It makes a lot of things much easier than `mysql_` (which is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) btw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select first_name, middle_name, last_name, address, mothers_name from tabel");
 while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
      $firstname=$s['first_name'];
      $middlename=$s['middle_name'];
      $lastname=$s['last_name'];    
      $name_all[]= "$firstname"."&nbsp;$middlename"."&nbsp;$lastname";
  }
for($i=0;$i<=count($name_all)-1;$i++){
  for($j=$i+1;$j<=count($name_all)-1;$j++){
    $result[]=checkforsimilarity($name_all[$i],$name_all[$j]);
  }
}
echo "<pre>";
die(print_r($result));

function checkforsimilarity($a,$b){
    if($a!=$b){
        similar_text($a,$b,$percent);
        return "<br />percentage of similarity between $a and $b is $percent <br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i didn get it, i have database 5 records, it should be every 1 record matched each record, it should be out 25 records. Please help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `$name_all` to itself in this function:

```
similar_text($name_all, $name_all, $percent);
```

Naturally, the comparison is 100% since $name_all is equal to itself.

Comment: I dont understand how to compare on the next records on database ?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try to do it within a MySQL query?

I haven't tested it but I think this will help:

```
SELECT 
    User.*,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    (COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE first_name='Popular')) * 100 AS 'Percentage', 
FROM 
    User
WHERE last_name='Popular'
GROUP BY User.first_name;
```

I am sure this will work, but you might need to edit it according to your need.

Comment: first name always change not just 'Popular', can be 'margareth', can be 'john'. I stiil didnt get it ??

Comment: so just pass User.first_name instead of Popular..i mean use self join by giving different name for table and pass it to where condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
Getting percentage using php code.Try this
 <?php
      $sql=mysql_query("select first_name, middle_name, last_name, address, mothers_name from tabel");
    $cnt=0;
     while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
      {
          $firstname=$s['first_name'];
          $middlename=$s['middle_name'];
          $lastname=$s['last_name'];    
          $name_all= "$firstname"."&nbsp;$middlename"."&nbsp;$lastname";
          if(isset($arr[$name_all])){
            $arr[$name_all] = $arr[$name_all]+1;
          }else{
            $arr[$name_all] = 1;
          }
          $cnt++;
      }
      echo $cnt;
      foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        echo $key."  percent=". ROUND(($val/$cnt)*100,2)."</br>";
      }
    ?>
```